# Category of Manifolds and Maps: TOP $\supseteq$ TRI $\supseteq$ PL $\supseteq$ DIFF?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, triangulations

Please let me denote the following

- (TOP) topological manifolds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold
- (PDIFF), for piecewise differentiable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDIFF
- (PL) piecewise-linear manifolds  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_manifold#Smooth_manifolds
- (DIFF) the smooth manifolds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Definition
- (TRI) triangulable manifolds  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_%28topology%29

we consider the **category** of manifolds and their maps based on what I learned from Wikipedia above links.

Is it true that the above **categories** have the following relations:

> (1) TOP $\supseteq$ TRI ?
>
> Namely, every TRI must be TOP manifolds?
>
> (2) TRI $\supseteq$ PL ?
>
> Namely, every PL must be TRI manifolds?
>
> (3) TRI $\supseteq$ DIFF ?
>
> Namely, every DIFF must be TRI manifolds?
>
> (4) PL $\supseteq$ DIFF ?
>
> Namely, every DIFF must be PL manifolds?
>
> (5) So in a short summary, is it true that
>
> $$\text{ TOP $\supseteq$ TRI $\supseteq$ PL $\supseteq$ DIFF} ?$$

(If what I said in (5) is false, what are their intersections, unions and complements of these categories?)

p.s. This is based on an improved unanswer question from MSE a week ago. I am sorry I hope more experts can fill in this question. Thanks! <3

Comment: Perhaps include a link to the MSE question. i.e. An question that is unanswered on MSE may still be closed here.

Comment: thanks, vote up, a more basic MSE question is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278365

Comment: There is no such thing as a PDIFF manifold. PDIFF is only a type of map from a PL manifold to a Diff manifold. Also, while people say that DIFF$\subset$PL, that is technically false and the true statement is subtle. Finally, no one considers TRI as a category. What are the morphisms? Is the double suspension of a homology sphere an object in this category not isomorphic to the sphere? Maybe they should consider a category, but probably they shouldn't.